# Should I let someone overtake my car if there is not enough space to do it?

Tags: traffic

This question came up in my driver license test (in Japan).

I found this question hard to answer because not allowing someone to overtake you may cause an accident (after all, you may be mistaken about the available space). However, if indeed there is no enough space, it may cause an accident.

I was unable to find the answer available in English here, so I'm guessing other countries may have similar rules.

The correct answer for this question will be a quote (and a link) to an official (or credible) source about this issue here in Japan or alternatively in any other country.

Comment: Are you normally expected to stop other people from doing illegal things with their cars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that you will find an official answer to that question. No law allows you to block passing (even if passing is illegal). Therefore, you must allow passing. There are laws against obstructing traffic. [Japanese law](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail/?id=2962&vm=02&re=02) addresses this, defining obstructing progress as

> starting to move or continuing to move in circumstances that would
> likely cause another vehicle or streetcar to have to suddenly change
> speed or direction in order to avoid danger

You'd have to specify *how* you intend to "not let" a person pass you, but I can't imagine what you could do that would not be "obstructing progress". A [recent anti-road rage law](https://mainichi.jp/english/articles/20200605/p2g/00m/0na/094000c) allows license revocation for violation.

Answer (score 0):

[The Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/using-the-road-159-to-203) in England, Scotland, and Wales has Rule 168 which covers how to act when being overtaken:

> **Being overtaken**. If a driver is trying to overtake you, maintain a steady course and speed, slowing down if necessary to let the vehicle pass. Never obstruct drivers who wish to pass. Speeding up or driving unpredictably while someone is overtaking you is dangerous. Drop back to maintain a two-second gap if someone overtakes and pulls into the gap in front of you.

If someone were to overtake you during the driving test in England, Scotland, and Wales, you would be expected to follow the rule above. You are not responsible for their choice to overtake (unless you are driving particularly slowly for no good reason, which would count against you in the test) but you must not deliberately obstruct them.